# How can I use Firebase Auth token for YouTube API access token

Tags: firebase, react-native, youtube-data-api, react-native-firebase

I'm working on a React native application and want to use Firebase auth token for the YouTube API.

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    credentials.email,
    credentials.password
   ).then( ()=>{})
```

What is the right way to achieve this?

Comment: What's the question here? Is the code working? Is there an error?

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Auth token is a JWT, which is not a valid OAuth2 token that can be used for the Youtube API. If you want to access youtube, you'll have to sign in there separately with their [documented authentication flow](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication).

Comment: I think we can get oauth2 token when we sign in with google using firebase.

Comment: When you sign in with Google that is indeed possible, but in this question the user is signing in to Firebase with email+password, so no OAuth token is ever minted.

Comment: ohh okay got it